# Restructure classic thesis project with subfolders using Kile

Tags: auxiliary-files, kile, build-system

I would like to change the folder structure of the [ClassicThesis project](https://code.google.com/p/classicthesis/). My current folder setup looks like this.

```
|-- bib // Some *.bib files.
|-- bst // Some *.bst files.
|-- cfg // Configuration tex file and sty file.
|-- fbm // Front back matter.
|-- img // Images
|-- prj // The main tex file.
|-- src // All tex files that contain content.
|-- CHANGES
|-- COPYING
|-- README
```

I changed all the paths to match the new directory structure. Thus [Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) complains about accessing the various files.

```
/usr/local/bin/pdflatex: Not writing to ../fbm/Titlepage.aux (openout_any = p).

! I can't write on file `../fbm/Titlepage.aux'.
\@include ...\immediate \openout \@partaux #1.aux 
                                                  \immediate \write \@partau...
l.87 \include{../fbm/Titlepage}

(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit; default file extension is `.tex')
Please type another output file name
! Emergency stop.
\@include ...\immediate \openout \@partaux #1.aux 
                                                  \immediate \write \@partau...
l.87 \include{../fbm/Titlepage}

!  ==&gt; Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on ClassicThesis.log.
```

When I remove the subdirectory path *Kile* produces a PDF with zero bytes.

**Optional:**
If possible, I would also like to have separate folder for the binary and temporary files. Saying, the PDF would go into `bin/` and the *.aux files would go into `tmp/`.

Comment: Don't use `\include`: TeX Live inhibits writing in directories whose path includes going above the current working directory. `\input` doesn't suffer from this limitation, as it doesn't use an `.aux` file for each input file like `\include` does.

Comment: Nice. That works. Thank you. So how can I grand you the answer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setup clashes with the "paranoid" setting of TeX Live (and MiKTeX, also) when it comes to writing files. You see it in the information line

```
/usr/local/bin/pdflatex: Not writing to ../fbm/Titlepage.aux (openout_any = p)
```

The distribution is set up so that TeX programs never open for writing files whose path includes going up from the working directory, or an absolute path; if you use `\include`, then you run into this limitation, as

```
\include{<path>/filename}
```

starts writing a `filename.aux` file in the same directory as `filename.tex`.

An easy solution is to use `\input` instead of `\include`, because reading files has no limitation about paths.

You can also set the output directories, using a command line option for `pdflatex`, namely `--output-dir=./tmp`, for example; but this will be used also for the produced PDF file.

Comment: Thx! Is there a way to include the output directory option with the *.tex file so I could add the setting into my version control?

Comment: @JJD No, this is an "engine option", which must be launched before the file is read. However there *might* be some editor related trick; for example, with TeXworks it's possible to specify in the `.tex` file which command to run for compiling it when the green arrow is pressed, and this command can be a script. I don't know with Kile.